# prove that f is a surjection

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let C be a partition of a given set A.

Prove that there exists a set B and $ f : A \rightarrow B$ such that

$ \quad $ (i) f is surjective

$\quad $ (ii) $ C = \{\{x \in A : f(x)=y\} : y \in B \}.  $

Let $ C = A_1 \cup A_2 ... \cup A_n$, n = infinity if A is infinite set.

Let f be a function s.t. $ \forall x,y \in A, \exists i \in \{1,2,....n\} $ where $ x,y \in A_i \iff f(x) = f(y) = i. $

$ B = \{1,2,...n\}. $

Take any $ y \in B,  f(x) = y, \forall x  \in A_y $. Therefore, f is surjective

I am not sure if this proof is correct?

Comment: Is there something you are leaving out? What is the context in how $C$ gets involved I don't understand. Is everything written correctly?

Comment: @DerekLuna I have edited the question

Comment: The edit is not clear. Is $C$ a generic partition, or is $C$ defined as $\{\{x \in A : f(x) = y\} : y \in B\}$? But in the second case, since $B$ is not defined, $C$ is not defined either.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco C is a generic partition. We have to prove that there is a set B and a surjective function f : A -> B, such that C is defined as mentioned above

Comment: I think your statement of what you are trying to prove is wrong. I think that given $A$ and partition $C$ you want to prove the existence of a set $B$, a function $f:A\to B$ which is (i) surjective (ii) satisfies the condition you have on $C,f$.

Comment: Your proof has the right idea, but won't do when $C$ is infinite unless you write it properly. Better to take $B=C$ and define $f(x)=Y$ whenever $x\in Y\in C$. Then you use properties of "partition" to show $f$ is a function, and is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your attempt. First, $C$ is a **set** of subsets of $A$, not the union of those sets. Next, there is no reason to think that $C$ can be enumerated by the natural numbers: we might, for instance, have the partition

$$\big\{\{x,-x\}:x\in\Bbb R\big\}$$

of $\Bbb R$, which has uncountably many members. Finally, there may not be any natural way to index the members of $C$ by numbers of any kind. Fortunately, there is no need to do so: we can in a sense index them by themselves.

Just let $B=C$, and for each $a\in A$ let $f(a)$ be the unique member of $C$ containing $a$. Clearly $f$ is surjective, since every member of $C$ is non-empty. Let $c\in C$; then for each $a\in A$ we have $f(a)=c$ iff $a\in c$, so $c=\{a\in A:f(a)=c\}$. Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
C&=\{c:c\in C\}\\
&=\big\{\{a\in A:f(a)=c\}:c\in C\big\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is an arbitrary partition then it looks like one can take $B = \{c_{1},...c_{n},...\}$ where $c_{i}$ corresponds to the first element in the $i$th partition subset of $A$. If you have a uncountable partition set and/or a "first element" is not defined then one can choose one using a random function. However, I don't know how to make this rigourous because it completely depends on what the partitions are. If the partitions are intervals then of course you can take all midpoints. If it is a partition of a tricky nowhere continuous function then you might need to be a bit more creative.